# Tapestry 5.4 and HTML5 audio tag

Tags: java, html, audio, html5-audio, tapestry

I am using Tapestry 5.4-beta26 to create a web site. I want to play a sound on my `Index.tml` page. For that I am using HTML5 audio tag.
This is the code for audio tag:

```
<audio preload="auto" controls="true">
    <source src="E:\sound.mp3" />
</audio>
```

On the page player looks like this
[image]

When I use the same code in regular html page it works like it should.
Can you tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Tapestry issue. It's a browser security issue. Any HTML page served by a web server (your Tapestry app is running in a web server/servlet container such as Jetty or Tomcat) needs to access resources through the web server, not via the local file system. Put your sound.mp3 file in a directory served by your web server (e.g. within your Tapestry project), change the src attribute to match, and it will work fine.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can I configure my tomcat server to allow access to access those files?

Comment: Yes, most servlet containers can act like simple web servers in that way. Look at aliases -- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you.